# useless class storage specifier in empty declaration

Tags: c, enums

gcc 4.4.1 c89

I have the following code:

```
static enum states
{
    ACTIVE,
    RUNNING,
    STOPPED,
    IDLE
};
```

And I get a warning:

```
useless class storage specifier in empty declaration
```

However, if i remove the static keyword I don't get that warning.

I am compiling with the following flags:

```
-Wall -Wextra
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `;` after the `}` (probably not related, just thought I'd mention it)

Comment: Presumably the error was "useless" as you have in the question title and not "unless" as you have in your question 'body'.

Comment: @Andreas - Fixed, just where I typed it in the question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You get the message because you're not actually *declaring*, you're only *defining* something, namely an enumeration named "states".  You can later use this definition to declare a variable of that type.  That variable may be a static or instance variable, but the definition doesn't need (and shouldn't have) the storage specifier attached to it.

Answer (score 16):

Your `enum` declaration is defining a type, but it is not also declaring an object of that type.

`static` only applies to variables and functions so, as the compiler says, it is useless in the context in which you have it.

Answer (score 7):

What do you want the static to do? It serves there to give variables defined in the declaration internal linkage:

```
static enum states { ... } a;
```

As a shortcut for

```
enum states { ... };
static enum states a;
```

Giving "a" internal linkage. But since you don't define a variable there in your code, it is useless in fact (if not illegal).

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
static enum states
{
    ACTIVE,
    RUNNING,
    STOPPED,
    IDLE
} avar;
```

which actually creates  a static variable called avar.  Only variables can be static, not types.